# Quais as diferenças entre jQuery e jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, front-end, jquery-mobile

Estava lendo hoje sobre o framework jQuery Mobile e pelo que entendi ele seria para o jQuery como o Bootstrap é para o CSS.

Não sei se entendi corretamente, mas fica a duvida: jQuery Mobile também tem as mesmas funcionalidades do jQuery convencional?

E agora que cada vez mais acessos a internet vem do mobile, compensa mais usar o jQuery Mobile no lugar do jQuery convencional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Framework para front-end mobile

A definição do próprio fabricante:

> jQuery Mobile is a touch-friendly UI framework built on jQuery Core
>   that works across all popular mobile, tablet and desktop platforms.

Isso responde a primeira pergunta sobre ter as mesmas funcionalidades do jQuery. Isso acontece porque esse framework é uma extensão do jQuery e é direcionado para a construção do front-end da aplicação. Assim, para que ele funciona você precisa instalar o jQuery.

Sobre a sua analogia com o Bootstrap e CSS, acredito que possa funcionar, porém o Bootstrap é quase tudo CSS e o jQuery Mobile tem outras funções além da parte de estilos, mas não vejo problema para facilitar o entendimento.

Explicando um pouco mais, esse framework tem a intenção de facilitar o desenvolvimento de sites "responsivos" e direcionados a dispositivos móveis, ou seja, quando o uso em desktop não é a prioridade. Porém caso o usuário de desktop acesse, ele conseguirá navegar e utilizar também.

A ideia é que você não precise se preocupar com o tamanho da tela do celular ou do tablet que estiver acessando o site. Isso é interessante porque você pode programar em HTML5 e a sua aplicação vai funcionar para qualquer dispositivo móvel sem a necessidade de escrever código nativo do dispositivo. Porém, terá algumas limitações, é claro, principalmente ao que se refere ao sensores dos aparelhos.

Acho que não vale a pena entrar em detalhes de como funciona ou exemplos porque imagino que a questão seja mais relacionada ao conceito do framework. Se quiser explorar mais, pode acessar a [página demo](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/).

Sobre a sua pergunta se compensa utilizar um ou o outro, acredito que com a explicação ela perde o sentido. Você poderá usar tudo do jQuery quando estiver usando o jQuery Mobile. Talvez a pergunta seria se compensa usar ele ao invés de outra abordagem. Por exemplo, o Bootstrap também te oferece design "responsivo" que irá funcionar independente do tamanho da tela do dispositivo, porém o jQuery Mobile tem muitas outras funcionalidades e o Bootstrap é mais para a parte visual.

Para essa última questão comparativa, melhor colocar em outra pergunta. IMHO compensa o jQuery Mobile apenas se a aplicação for de uso exclusivo em mobile.

Answer (score 2):

Bom, vou dar aqui meu entendimento da diferença entre eles, corrijam-me se estiver errado.

**JQuery**

O objetivo principal do JQuery é simplificar e de certa forma padronizar o JavaScript cross-browser, facilitando e mexendo com coisas como manipulação de elementos HTML e fazendo requests HTTP

**JQueryUI**

É um conjunto de elementos de interface (botões, datepickers, sliders, abas, essas coisas), feitos usando JQuery, ou seja, JQueryUI precisa de JQuery pra funcionar. (JQueryUI = JQuery User Interface)

Esses dois de cima foram feitos para **serem uma adição** ao seu site (seja ele desktop ou mobile), adicionando funcionalidades como as que eu citei acima.

**JQuery Mobile**

O JQuery Mobile, diferentemente dos outros dois de cima, é um framework completo para desenvolvimento. A intenção é que ele seja o ponto de partida do seu site. Ele requer JQuery e usa funcionalidades do JQuery e do JQuery para facilitar a construção de sites Mobile.

Outra diferença é que JQuery e JQuery UI são feitos para serem usados como se fossem uma camada extra no seu HTML e CSS. Por exemplo, você tem um `input` para escolher data, e transforma ele em um plugin com o JQuery:

`$('#meu_input').datepicker();`

Já o JQuery Mobile disponibiliza maneiras de escolher aonde esses elementos diferenciados aparecerão apenas com o uso de HTML:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true">
    <li><a href="#">Acura</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Audi</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">BMW</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Cadillac</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ferrari</a></li>
</ul>
```

O atributo `data-role` diz ao JQuery mobile para tornar essa lista em um componente amigável para as plataformas mobile. `data-inset` e `data-filter` definem atributos desse elemento, sem usar uma linha sequer de JavaScript.

Usei um pouco de conhecimento próprio e [dessa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10391856/difference-between-jquery-and-jquery-mobile) pergunta do SO em inglês para formular essa resposta